# Grouping in XQuery FLWOR to generate a space-separated list of values for each key

Tags: xquery, flwor

I have a XML with 5 articles, each one of them:

```
<root>
<article>
    <c0>
        <number>
        </number>
        <price> 
        </price>
   </c0>
   <c1>
        <name> NewArtc1
        </name>
        <nameUs>TheBest
        </nameUs>
    </c1>
    <c2>
        <name> c2_1
        </name> 
        <nameUs>NotTheBest
        </nameUs>
     </c2>
    <c2>
        <name> c2_2
        </name> 
        <nameUs>TheBest
        </nameUs>
    </c2>
    <c2>    
        <name> c2_3
        </name> 
        <nameUs>NotTheBest
        </nameUs>
   </c2>
   <c2>
        <name> c2_4
        </name> 
        <nameUs>TheBest
        </nameUs>
   </c2>
   <c2>
        <name> c2_5
        </name>     
        <nameUs>NotTheBest
        </nameUs>
   </c2>            
  </article>
<article> ...
</root>
```

Each item has several characteristics (c0, c1, c2, etc.). I need, using XQuery (FLWOR), to return the names of c1. followed by the names of c2 whose text of the nameUs node matches that of the nameUs node c1 (there are 5 c2 for each article) The output format should be, for each article:

```
<c1> 
  <name>NewArtc1</name>
  <c2s>c2_2 c2_4</c2s>
</c1>

<c1> 
  <name>NewArtc2</name>
  <c2s>c2_3 c2_5</c2s>
</c1>
```

Please help me :/ I've done this, but it returns pairs, not the output format I need:

```
for $a in doc("articles.xml")//article, $i in 1 to 5
let $b:=$a/c1/nameUs
let $c:=$a/c2[$i]/nameUs
where $b/text() and $b/text()=$c/text()
return <c1>{$b/name}<c2>{$c/name/text()}</c2></c1>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: for $a in doc("articles.xml")//article, $i in 1 to 5
let $b:=$a/c1/nameUs
let $c:=$a/c2[$i]/nameUs
where $b/text() and $b/text()=$c/text()
return <c1>{$b/name}<c2>{$c/name/text()}</c2></c1>

Comment: please help me, I do not know what else I can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like...

```
for $arcticle in /root/article
let $name   := $arcticle/c1/name/normalize-space()
let $nameUs := $arcticle/c1/nameUs/normalize-space()
return
    <c1>
        <name>{$name}</name>
        <c2s>{$arcticle/c2[normalize-space(nameUs)=$nameUs]/name/normalize-space()}</c2s>
    </c1>
```